# How to add $(…):$(...) in Docker Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I need to run the following commands in the docker-compose:

```
- '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
- '$(which docker):$(which docker)'
```

I found a solution for such a format:

```
- ${DOCKER_PATH}:/usr/bin/docker:ro
```

But in my case, I need to run this format $(..):$(..),

Is there any simple solution from the docker-compose it solve the problem?

I tried this:

```
DOCKER_PATH=$(which docker) docker-compose up

volumes:
   - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
   - ${DOCKER_PATH}:/usr/bin/docker:ro
```

But I get error:

```
ERROR: Invalid bind mount spec "59f5e4fa06257c16a046ae7e5163401349f1c0bb394c881bcdf557a2f544811c:$(which:rw": Invalid volume destination path: '$(which' mount path must be absolute.
```

Comment: You're trying to put the docker binary from the host into the container?

Comment: I want jenkins in docker with access to host docker.

Answer (score 1):

The following doesn't work

```
DOCKER_PATH=$(which docker) docker-compose up

volumes:
   - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
   - ${DOCKER_PATH}:/usr/bin/docker:ro
```

Because variable substitution needs to be inside **double quotes** (single quotes wont work), like this

```
- "${DOCKER_PATH}:/usr/bin/docker:ro"
```

You can read more about it here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution